# how to initialize and add struct to vector in single line

Tags: c++, struct

I was wondering if there is a way to initialize and add struct in a vector in a single line something like

```
vector<Row> list;

//Row t;

list.push_back(Row t ={"",23});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
list.push_back(Row{"",23});
```

as well as this:

```
list.push_back({"",23});
```

---

The above works for C++11 and a modern compiler, e.g., GCC or Clang. If you can't enable C++11 or it is not supported with your compiler, you need to add a constructor to `Row`:

```
struct Row
{
    Row( const std::string& d, int w ) : data( d ), weight( w ) {}

    // ...
};
```

and you can use:

```
list.push_back(Row("",23));
```

Comment: i am using visual studio and its not working.                    typedef struct Row{

 string data;
 int weight;
 
}Row;          list.push_back(Row{"1111", 1});  error: struct Row..type name is not allowed

Comment: @user734861 Updated for older compilers.

Comment: @user734861 `typedef struct X { ... } X;` is pointless in C++, simple `struct X { ... };` works as well.

Comment: For completeness: with C++11 you also have `emplace_back`. E.g. `list.emplace_back("", 23);`.